# Clean Install With Windows Managed Mirror

Tags: windows-8, mirroring

ok so i have a win 7 pro with 2 1TB drives that are mirrored using the windows disk management mirror.

I am planning on doing a new / clean install on this PC with windows 8 and afraid that the disk will get lost, anyone know?

have not been able to find any documentation on this at all.....

Comment: i will prob be able to answer this question in about an hour, just found a drive im not using so going to keep my current drive safe for a min and try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well that was nerve racking, was so afraid to loose everything.
was very smooth!

when i got into the drive manager the drive was marked with an exclamation point, right click and hit import, message came up saying import 2 drives as mirrored and TADA done